# Swift 4 in Xcode 9 - Read data in core data failed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9

My function read() has a predicate which can not work normally , I set the “no” 0 can read all data, can not if I set other.

```
class DataClass
{
    private(set) var no: Int16?
    private(set) var title: String?
    private(set) var content: NSAttributedString?

    init(no: Int16,
         title: String,
         content: NSAttributedString)
    {
        self.no = no
        self.title = title
        self.content = content
    }
}


func read(no: Int16) -> DataClass?
    {
        let ReadData = DataClass()

        let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Note", in: managedObjectContext)

        let request = NSFetchRequest<Note>(entityName: "Note")
        request.fetchOffset = 0
        request.entity = entity

        print("noBtnDn: \(no)")
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "no == %@", NSNumber(value: no))
        request.predicate = predicate

        do{
            let results = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
            print("results`count: \(results.count)")
            for note in results
            {
                //ReadData.title = note.title!
                //ReadData.content = (note.content as? NSAttributedString)!
                ReadData.ReadFromNote(note: note)
                print("no: \(note.no)")
            }
        }
        catch{
            print("Failed to read data.")
            return nil
        }
        return ReadData

    }
```

It print *results`count: 24* when no=0 (the count of all data is 24),print *results` count: 0* when no!=0. The “no” of data has no 0, they begin at 1.

So when no=0 , print

```
noBtnDn: 0
results` count: 24
no: 1
no: 2
no: 3
...
no: 24
```

I don’t know why it can’t find correct “no”, is my function use incorrectly ?

Comment: Can you try to pass `no` without converting to NSNumber?

Comment: @IvanSmetanin I tried, it returns a error in this NSPredicate line at the runtime when no!=0, but when no=0, it could read all data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your class matches the CoreData Properties ?

Also did you try to make the optional Int16  to an non Optional ?

Comment: My class property no is an optional Int16 , and CoreData property no is an non optional, maybe this is the key to problem, I will try to change it later , thanks!

Comment: I have tried this and it still failed. It has no change.

Comment: I make it, just change no to %K and add “no” after!